# Xamarin android webview dont open camera

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webview, camera

I am really beginner in xamarin.
I need an app, what is load a website in webview. The site need file uploading `<input type="file" accept="image/*" />`. In mobile browser it is perfect, can open camera or choose from storage.
IOS webview working too, I gave permission and it is OK. But in android, I tried a lot of code, but the best result a filechooser without camera, and it doesn’t even load the image I select from storage.
Can anyone help, what is the problem?
My current code:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
    private static IValueCallback mUploadMessage;
    private static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    public static  IValueCallback mUMA; 
    public static int FCR = 1;  

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        var web = this.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.wv);
        web.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        web.SetWebChromeClient(new myWebChromeClient(this));
        web.LoadUrl....
    }
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
        {
            if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
            Android.Net.Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != Result.Ok ? null : intent.Data;
            mUploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }
    public class myWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient
    {
        Activity mActivity = null;
        public myWebChromeClient(Activity activity)
        {
            mActivity = activity;
        }
        public override bool OnShowFileChooser(WebView webView, IValueCallback filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
        {
            if (MainActivity.mUMA != null)
            {
                mUMA.OnReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mUMA = filePathCallback;
            Intent captureIntent = fileChooserParams.CreateIntent();
            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
            contentSelectionIntent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
            contentSelectionIntent.SetType("*/*");
            Intent[] intentArray;
            if (captureIntent != null)
            {
                intentArray = new Intent[] { captureIntent };
            }
            else
            {
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }

            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionChooser);
            chooserIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraIntent, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraTitle, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraInitialIntents, intentArray);
            mActivity.StartActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
            return base.OnShowFileChooser(webView, filePathCallback, fileChooserParams);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, do you want to get a fresh picture from camera, or you want the user to choose between a fresh image and gallery image?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, I want both.I want to pop up the filechooser that the user can choose to take a photo or choose from an existing one

Comment: I guess you were looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59027312/192373)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write a demo to open the camera by Input button in HTML page, I used local HTML page to make a test, here is running GIF.

[image]

Here is my code in `MainActivity.cs`.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Webkit;
using Android.Content;
using Java.IO;
using Android.Net;
using Android.Support.V4.Content;
using Android;
using Android.Content.PM;

namespace MyWebviewDemo
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true,LaunchMode =Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        private static IValueCallback mUploadMessage;
        private static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
        public static IValueCallback mUMA;
        public static int FCR = 1;
        public static IValueCallback mUploadCallbackAboveL;
        public static int PHOTO_REQUEST=10023;
        public static Uri imageUri;
       public static MainActivity Instance;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            WebView webView1 = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
            webView1.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webView1.Settings.UseWideViewPort=true;
            webView1.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode=true;
            webView1.Settings.DomStorageEnabled=true;
            webView1.Settings.DefaultTextEncodingName="UTF-8";
            webView1.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(this));
            webView1.SetWebChromeClient(new myWebChromeClient(this));
            webView1.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
            Instance = this;
 if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.Camera) != (int)Permission.Granted)
            {
                RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.Camera }, 0);
            }


            //开启存储权限
            if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) != (int)Permission.Granted)
            {
                RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage, Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage }, 0);
            }




        }
        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent intent)
        {
            if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
            {
                if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
                Android.Net.Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != Result.Ok ? null : intent.Data;
                mUploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(result);
                mUploadMessage = null;
            }else if (requestCode== PHOTO_REQUEST)
            {
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != Result.Ok ? null : intent.Data;

                if (mUploadCallbackAboveL != null)
                {
                    onActivityResultAboveL(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
                }
                else if (mUploadMessage != null)
                {
                    mUploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(result);
                    mUploadMessage = null;
                }

                //mUploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(result);
                //mUploadMessage = null;
            }
        }
        private void onActivityResultAboveL(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if (requestCode != PHOTO_REQUEST || mUploadCallbackAboveL == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            Uri[] results = null;
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                results = new Uri[] { imageUri };
                results[0] = MainActivity.imageUri;
                //if (data == null)
                //{
                //    results = new Uri[] { imageUri };
                //}
                //else
                //{
                //    results[0] = MainActivity.imageUri;
                //    //get the data
                //    string dataString = data.DataString;
                //    ClipData clipData = data.ClipData;
                //    if (clipData != null)
                //    {
                //        results = new Uri[clipData.ItemCount];
                //        for (int i = 0; i < clipData.ItemCount; i++)
                //        {
                //            ClipData.Item item = clipData.GetItemAt(i);
                //            results[i] = item.Uri;
                //        }
                //    }

                //    if (dataString != null)
                //        results = new Uri[] { Uri.Parse(dataString) };
                //}
            }
            mUploadCallbackAboveL.OnReceiveValue(results);
            mUploadCallbackAboveL = null;
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    internal class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        private MainActivity mainActivity;

        public MyWebViewClient(MainActivity mainActivity)
        {
            this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
        }
    }

    public class myWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient
    {
        Activity mActivity = null;
        public myWebChromeClient(Activity activity)
        {
            mActivity = activity;
        }
        public override bool OnShowFileChooser(WebView webView, IValueCallback filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
        {
            MainActivity.mUploadCallbackAboveL = filePathCallback;
            TakePhoto();
            //if (MainActivity.mUMA != null)
            //{
            //    MainActivity.mUMA.OnReceiveValue(null);
            //}
            //MainActivity.mUMA = filePathCallback;
            //Intent captureIntent = fileChooserParams.CreateIntent();
            //Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
            //contentSelectionIntent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryOpenable);
            //contentSelectionIntent.SetType("*/*");
            //Intent[] intentArray;
            //if (captureIntent != null)
            //{
            //    intentArray = new Intent[] { captureIntent };
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    intentArray = new Intent[0];
            //}

            //Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionChooser);
            //chooserIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraIntent, contentSelectionIntent);
            //chooserIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraTitle, "Image Chooser");
            //chooserIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraInitialIntents, intentArray);
            //mActivity.StartActivityForResult(chooserIntent, MainActivity.FCR);
            return true;
        }

        private void TakePhoto()
        {
            File fileUri = new File(Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path);
            //MainActivity.imageUri = Uri.FromFile(fileUri);
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >=Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.N)
            {
                if (!fileUri.Exists())
                {
                    fileUri.Mkdir();
                }
                File file = new File(fileUri, SystemClock.CurrentThreadTimeMillis()+".jpg");
                MainActivity.imageUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(mActivity, "com.companyname.mywebviewdemo" + ".fileprovider", file);//通过FileProvider创建一个content类型的Uri
            }
            PhotoUtils.TakePicture(MainActivity.Instance, MainActivity.imageUri, MainActivity.PHOTO_REQUEST);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my Util.cs to take a camera.

```
 public static void TakePicture(Activity activity, Android.Net.Uri imageUri, int requestCode)
        {
           
            Intent intentCamera = new Intent();
          
            intentCamera.SetAction(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
            

           // intentCamera.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, imageUri);
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.N)
            {

                intentCamera.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission); 
            }
            if (activity != null)
            {
                activity.StartActivityForResult(intentCamera, requestCode);
            }
        }
```

I update my demo to github, you can downdload it and test it.

https://github.com/851265601/Xamarin.Android_ListviewSelect/blob/master/MyWebviewDemo.zip

Comment: I have two question for this solution. 1. Sometimes the input doesn't get the picture (when I use the camera), when I use breakpoint and check the code step by step, it always get the picture, maybe the picture processing or something like this? 2. Camera intent closing and webview loading after photo shooting takes too long, what causes it?

Comment: It doesn't work anymore I think ?